# using tightvnc 2.7.10 src in neatbeans

Tags: c++, vnc, vnc-viewer, tightvnc

I am a naive in project development,for my current task i have to work with already available source code of tightvnc 2.7.10(it's in cpp).Please help  how to open it in netbeans and execute it
P.S Source code can be downloaded from [here](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php)

Comment: Please check netbeans tutorial and come back if you are having any specific issues while compiling/building the code

Comment: there is no build script in the source code,netbeans is asking for make file or build script i am not able to figure it out